# PHP long script behavior on a multi user enviroment

Tags: php, multiprocessing, behavior

Maybe this question has been asked before, but i couldn't find it on google...

Let's say that i have a script on the server that takes a few seconds to end, what happens if another user tries to access the same script? does php make the last user wait until finished? or will it serve a copy of the script, allowing several users to run the same script at the same time?

does this behavior can be configured on php.ini?

regards

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5363658/1592398

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script runs for each user separately, so several users have access at the same time, unless your Server's processors are busy, then a user may have to wait for last process to end. If you want multiple threads for the same user then consider [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php).